# Feasibility of Docker image deploying without dockerhub.com and using in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am trying to use Kubernetes and Jenkins for my deployment of micro services developed using Spring Boot. When I am exploring many YouTube videos and other documentation tutorials are using dockerhub.com as keeping published image as repository.

Can I deploy docker image in Kubernetes by using Jenkins docker image build without using this dockerhub.com ? Means I don't want to share client code in a public place. So can I use Jenkins without dockerhub.com?

Comment: hi, you can persist your images in a private registry rather than using dockerhub registry. It's all about persistence. As you know that Jenkins is also running as a pod which can be terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to use *some* registry- kubernetes needs a registry URL to be able to pull and instantiate a particular image as a container in a pod. To avoid having the images themselves be publicly accessible you have 2 options:

- use a business account at a public registry. You can get one of these from Docker, or from other services like Google or Quay. When you push images using a business account, you get a private space in the public registry and only your account credentials can push and pull those images. In this case your Kubernetes- and your Jenkins- has to be configured with credentials derived from your account to be able to pull those private images into your cluster.
- run a private registry in your cluster or on your non-cluster infrastructure There are many flavors of private registries, including Docker's, Atlassian's, and many others. This keeps your images entirely on your infrastructure. The tradeoff is that you have to configure and run this as a production service, and most private registries suitable for production use have a lot of moving parts for scalable image storage, indexing, backup, and so forth.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Jonak Benton. Thank you for your response. I got the concept of registry. I am thinking about the second option. Setting a private registry on my cluster. Let me explore you points. But I have one more doubt. If the image is pulling from private registry , Then why the Jenkins using code repository link (Etc GitHub , SVN etc)? ..When I am wathcing youtube video , those people is also using dockerhub credentials and github code repository link. Since we are pulling Image from registry. So why we are again defining our code repository?.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the concern, but it is fine to use Jenkins to pull source code from a public or private code repository, perform a container image build on a Jenkins worker, then push the image to an image registry on private infrastructure. If there is a need to keep source code (as well as image builds) private, then the source code repository should be private as well, either private Github account, or a source code repository also running in the k8s cluster or on private infrastructure. Happy to answer more questions.

Comment: Can I create my Private registry for docker images within the  node where kubernetes master and Jenkins installed?.

Comment: Yes. You can even run it as a container- modulo proper configuration of storage- since registry applications are packaged and available on public registries. Whether it makes sense from a performance and reliability perspective to run it on a master depends on your requirements.